# Magento 2.3 Very High PHP-FPM CPU Usage

Tags: magento2, php, php-fpm

Using Magento 2.3 and after some extensive digging, it seems that either fotorama or another that loads the images on product list and product page runs several instances of PHP-FPM all at high usage, if there are a few photos on the product it can sometimes hang and keep loading. I then have to restart the PHP-FPM service for the page to load properly with the images.

The server is a VPS, running 16GB RAM and 6 Core CPU.

What should i be looking for next to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

These some solution for this case, you can check.

1. Disable Signed content (Don't need for developer mode)

   > insert into core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) values
   >   ('default',0, 'dev/static/sign', 0);
2. Make sure you have used SSD for store Magento 2 Source Code.
3. Make sure you have used the latest MySQL version.
4. You are developing, please enable developer mode and doing step 1.
5. If your site got too many products, please run `php bin/magento catalog:image:resize`
6. The suggestion is Use Redis cache and saves the session to DB or Redis

Comment: Thank you Hoang, since you wrote this i have done the following: Upgraded the server from centos 6 to 7, installed Litespeed enterprise alongside LiteMage and have noticed a slight improvement in image loading times but not huge. The catalog:image:resize has been running now for 23 hours currently on 30650 / 96454....will wait for it to finish and report back. :)

Comment: Let us know what did the trick!

Comment: He is probably still waiting for catalog:image:resize to finish.